# wordpress random post from category that cycles through on homepage

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, wordpress

There is a "quote" section on my current WP theme (@ http://lillypillyps.com.au) home page that I would like to replace with a "cycling" banner of sorts.

Similar to the testimonials on [this site's header](http://nundoobah-retreat.com.au), I want it to display a random testimonial on page load and cycle through all others.

I have a posts cetegory called "testimonials" that I want it to pull the title and content from for this.

I've seen something close to this via http://wordpress.org/support/topic/show-random-posts-custom-fields?replies=10 but not quite what I want.  I was hoping there'd be a plug-in for it, but because I don't know what to call this, I can't find anything even remotely close.

Maybe, I can use a variation of this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
            $('#escape').fadeIn(3000).delay(2000).fadeOut(3000); 
            $("#quotes").load("quotes.html",function() {
        $quotes = $("p.quotes");
        var q = Math.floor( Math.random() * $quotes.length );
        $quotes.eq(q).addClass("next"); // set the next to fade
        f();        
    })
});
function f() {
    $(".next").fadeIn(3000).delay(2000).fadeOut(3000, function() {
        // fadeout ended, we prepare the next one
        $(this).removeClass("next");
        $(this).next("p.quotes").addClass("next");
        if($(".next").length==0) $("p.quotes:first").addClass("next");
        f();
    });
}
</script>
```

But using php scripting to pull from the specified category rather than from a flat html page...

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$array = get_posts(array('category' => 1));
shuffle($array);

foreach ($array as $post) {
    //Blah blah javascript
}


?>
```

Comment: this is very vague...   How will the javascript that goes within that code (i'm assuming via `echo "<script>javascriptfunction();</script>";` ) get the `<?php the_content(); ?>` and `<?php the_title(); ?>`

Comment: Make PHP echo a javascript array that contains each the_content and the_title(), then make your javascript functions cycle through the array that PHP has created.

Comment: Thanks Richard...  I put this in the too hard basket and managed to find a plugin that I could manipulate to get pretty close to what I want.  Cheers